# How do you use the MySQL NULL literal on Apache NiFi's PutSQL processor?

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I have a `PutSQL processor` on `Apache NiFi` and on the `SQL statement` property of the processor, I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (
    COL1,
    COL2
) VALUES (
    '${col1}',
    ${col2:equals('yes'):ifElse(NULL, '${col2}')}
);
```

As you can see, I need to dynamically check `col2` if it's equal to `yes` and then use MySQL's `NULL` but the NiFi Expression Language is complaining that it's an invalid expression because it can't parse `NULL`.